# Google Analytics just start tracking Windows Phone as an OS?

Tags: google-analytics, mobile

Just wondering if anyone else has dug into the Windows Phone traffic they have in Google Analytics?

The graph below describes it better than I can.  The timeline is showing the last year, and we have nothing before November.

[image]

Did Google just incorporate/recognize this lately?
Our tags haven't changed.

The other thing I notice is that if you check out the version, there are only visitors from 7.0 and 7.5.  Does Google only track 7.0 onwards, or can I find stats on earlier devices (i.e. Windows Phone 6.5, Windows Mobile 6.1 devices, etc...) somewhere else?  I would **really** prefer not to have to look by screen resolution, as that's a mess of information to look at.

Thanks in advance for any anecdotes/comments/answers people might be able to provide.

Comment: I just realized that I accepted this answer because it explains where the earlier devices sit in Google Analytics.  I still don't know why they didn't register before Nov 2011 though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous versions of the operating system on "windows" phones are under `Windows`, which on my analytics has subtypes CE and ME. What I don't know is how those subtypes map to the different versions of Windows CE. The [wikipedia article on Windows CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE) says

> Windows Mobile is best described as a subset of platforms based on a
>   Windows CE underpinning.

Comment: Looking at UA strings, I see that now.  
`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows CE; IEMobile 7.11)` = Windows mobile 6.1 device.  

I do see those hits going back over time.  What puzzles me is that the Windows phone has been out for a while.  It's possible that we didn't get visitors from one until November, but I suspect otherwise.

You are bang on though, that these older devices are CE.  I do see twice as many Opera visitors as IE, but that's an aside.  Think this means that Win ME and Win ME Mobile are picked up as the same (in Google)?  I notice most ME traffic is using Firefox.